# Can't get x forwarding to work with android

Tags: debian, ssh, raspberry-pi, android, xdotool

I'm trying to send keystrokes from my android to my Retropie using ssh. After a lot of searching I found that I have to use ssh with the `-X` flag which was already a hassle as most apps don't support flags. I fond one now (VX ConnectBot) and when I echo `$DISPLAY` I get `localhost:10` so x11 forwarding seems properly enabled. But when I try to do anything with xdotool like  `DISPLAY=':0' xdotool ...` I always get the error

`Error: Can't open display: (null)`.

Any ideas why? Or any other ideas on how I can control the keyboard from my android?

Answer (score 0):

If `$DISPLAY` is `localhost:10` when you're connecting from Android to Retropie, it indicates that X forwarding is in effect for X11 programs on the Retropie to the screen on Android.

When you specify `DISPLAY=':0'`, the command after that would be connecting to Retropie's local X display, not the remote display of the Android. In effect, you would be *undoing* the X forwarding to access the local display of the system that's running the command. To do that successfully, you would also need the local display's session cookie in your `~/.Xauthority` file (or in a file pointed to by the `$XAUTHORITY` environment variable).

Now, *have you confirmed that Retropie actually has an X server running?* The programs in it could be using the framebuffer device directly, eliminating the overhead of the X11 protocol. In a device like Retropie, that would make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Well okay... I think I'm just gonna buy a  keyboard. I've been digging through guides for hours now and apparently they're all not working. Thanks a lot for the effort, but it seems its not as straightforward as I thought to press a simple key on the remote machine.